# Image gradients become inaccurate when downscaling using a variety of different methods

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, python-imaging-library

We have a fairly complex image processing script written in Python which is using PIL and numpy. For one of the steps, we have a very sensitive multi channel gradients which is a lookup table. Once it has been created, it is saved down to multiple different smaller resolutions. When this happens however, the green channel, which has a gradient running left to right, suddenly appears to lose percision. It is supposed to lose 1 of 255 values every 50 pixels or so. Instead, it starts dropping by values of 2 at every 100 pixels. This causes huge issues and I can't figure out why PIL is doing it. However, I do see jumps of 1 in other portions of the map so I don't think its a simple as its missing one bit of precision. I also noticed on another channel, it seemed like the whole map was shifted by 1 value. The entire thing seems inaccurate once scaled, even when using the "Nearest" filter.

For the full size image, we create it from our numpy array with the following:

```
image = Image.fromarray(imageIn.astype(np.uint8))
```

We then scale it down:

```
new_image = image.resize(new_size, scaleFilter)
```

The scale is always half the largest and I have tried all available scale options.

We then save it to a PNG as follows:

```
new_image.save(file_name, 'PNG')
```

We save both the large one directly after step 1 with the same save command and it is fine. After the scale, we have the issue on the green channel. Any help would be great!

EDIT:

It now appears that it is likley an issue in SciPy. The following still causes the issue:

```
    new_array = misc.imresize(imageIn, (x_size, y_size, 4), interp='nearest')
    misc.imsave(file_name,new_array)
```

I do not understand how I am even getting the distortions with nearest. I am allocating this array as a float64, but it has to involve rounding issues within the code

EDIT #2:

I took this a step further and tried OSX built in program sips to download it and got the same distortion! I then tried it with Adobe After Effects and it worked fine. I then installed imagemagick which now works fine. I will still award the bounty to anyone who can explain why this is happening within all these methods.

EDIT #3

Per the request, here is a section of a sprite map scaled and unscaled. During creating these, I found the OSX's built in "Preview" application also causes scaling issues when scaling down so I actually had to use photoshop to get the original clip.

Original:

[image]

Scaled with distortions. Try looking at the green channel along the horizontal axis

[image]

Note that these clippings are not of the exact same pixels, but cut from the same area as you can see by the shape

EDIT #4

I have now tried doing this scaling via OpenGL within the application and I have found it happens there too! This has to do with some fundamental issue of doing bilinear interpolation with a fixed number of bits?

Comment: isn't 1/50 the same as 2/100? I'm confused.

Comment: Its jumping by 2 instead of 1, meaning it would appear to have half the precision.

Comment: What is `scaleFilter`?

Comment: I tried all the options available, but here is link to the documents if you are wondering what the legal options are:  https://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.0.0/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize

Comment: Both `imresize()` and `imsave()` internally call `toimage()`, which seems to rescale the pixel values to 0-255.

Comment: Your problem with SciPy is that it internally calls PIL to do resizing, that's why the behaviour is identical. I prefer OpenCV, specially if I'm working with numpy because there are no conversions back and forth (unlike PIL, an image loaded with cv2 is stored as a numpy array).

Comment: @bconstanzo - I just found it strange that the built in Mac utility sips also had a near identical distortion.

Comment: David could you please post an example gradient image (before it is scaled) and/or the code to generate it?  Also could you post a runnable example of the scaling code?  I think I know what is going on but it would be easier to show on a complete example

Comment: @AlexI - I just posted them

Comment: PIL ([see source](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/3.2.x/PIL/Image.py#L1548)) resizes in "premultiplied alpha" space, which results in some transparency information leaking into the color channels. The idea is to not blend the color of transparent and opaque pixels, which I guess is what one would want for a regular image, but it's no good for a lookup table. The problem is exaggerated (in PIL) due to use of `uint8` intermediaries.

Comment: @morningsun - This is the best answer I have seen. If you place it as an answer, I will award the bounty, but be aware, it expires tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code appears to do the right thing when scaling by 50%, using skimage:

```
import numpy
import skimage
import skimage.io

img = skimage.io.imread('uY173.png')

import skimage.transform

img50_order0 = skimage.img_as_ubyte( skimage.transform.rescale(img, 0.5, order=0, clip=True) )
img50_order1 = skimage.img_as_ubyte( skimage.transform.rescale(img, 0.5, order=1, clip=True) )

img50_lm = numpy.rint( skimage.transform.downscale_local_mean(img, (2,2,1), clip=True) )

import scipy.ndimage.interpolation

img50_nd = scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom(img, (0.5, 0.5, 1))

# plot section of green channel along horizontal axis
plot(img50_order0[50, :, 1])
plot(img50_order1[50, :, 1])
plot(img50_lm[50, :, 1])
plot(img50_nd[50, :, 1])
```

This does not (as far as I can tell) depend on PIL under the hood.  The source image is read as uint8, processed and rounded in subtly different ways in each one, resulting in a uint8 output.  The difference between all of these is never more than 1 though, and the steps are never size 2.